# Button.PerformClick not working properly and crashing when called

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an auto auth system. Basicly when you log in it store your data into internal storage to automatically log you next time.
I have an issue because I need to perform 2 click to log a user so to auto log him I do that:

```
        String username = data.substring(0,separatorPostion);
        String passwd = data.substring(separatorPostion+1);
        username_input.setText(username);
        passwd_input.setText(passwd);
        Log.w("DEBUG usrNameParsed: ",username);
        Log.w("DEBUG passParsed: ",passwd);
        ((View) findViewById(R.id.next_btn_username)).performClick();
        ((View) findViewById(R.id.next_btn_passwd)).performClick();
```

But, it crash. I can make the first perform click or the second one alone they both work but not together. For the purpose I need those 2 clicks because it's part of my auth system.
Thanks guys.

EDIT:
There is no real crash log this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: `But, it crash.` than share your crash log with question

Comment: I edited the post. With a real crash I think I would figure out what it can possibly come from but with that there is nothing I can do on my own (I don't have enough knowledge on android at the moment)

Comment: Are your trying to do user interface automation testing ?

Comment: Not for testing but yes it is pretty much that. I pre fill the fields with stored user data and then I need to click those 2 buttons to log the user in

Comment: are you getting these two logs printed : Log.w("DEBUG usrNameParsed: ",username);
        Log.w("DEBUG passParsed: ",passwd);

Comment: ((Button) findViewById(R.id.next_btn_username)).performClick(); and check you are passing the right id

Comment: @AmitRanjan Yes I get them only when I comment one of the 2 performClick otherwise I only get the log I put in the thread

Comment: can you post performClick code

Comment: @AmitRanjan Your solution works ! Thanks

Comment: What you made the changes :) Button ? B/w welcome, you can upvote i you wish

Comment: @AmitRanjan yes I change View to ImageButton in my case ;) I'm feeling dumb I didn't even test this ahah